# Pandas copy dataframe keeping only max value for rows with same index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have a dataframe that looks like

```
    value   otherstuff
0     4         x
0     5         x
0     2         x
1     2         x
2     3         x
2     7         x
```

what is a succinct way to get a new dataframe that looks like

```
    value   otherstuff
0     5         x
1     2         x
2     7         x
```

where rows with the same index have been dropped so only the row with the maximum 'value' remains? As far as I am aware there is no option in df.drop_duplicates to keep the max, only the first or last occurrence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `max` with `level=0`:

```
df.max(level=0)
```

Output:

```
   value otherstuff
0      5          x
1      2          x
2      7          x
```

OR, to address other columns mentioned in comments:

```
df.groupby(level=0,group_keys=False)\
  .apply(lambda x: x.loc[x['value']==x['value'].max()])
```

Output:

```
   value otherstuff
0      5          x
1      2          x
2      7          x
```

Comment: This works for his example but not in general. Presumably he wants the max _only_ with respect to the `value` column.

Comment: This is accomplishing the desired filter, but is actually dropping the other columns in the dataframe.

Comment: After the edit, this works beautifully, though it is slower than Mitch's solution. This method retains duplicates (which I didn't realize I had, so great)

Comment: super late, but how would you save the values left out to a new dataframe?

Comment: @LeLionJaune I am sorry, but I don't understand your desired result.  Can you reexplain?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `groupby.transform` to calculate the maximum value per group and then compare the value column with the maximum, if true, keep the rows:

```
df[df.groupby(level=0).value.transform('max').eq(df.value)]

#    value  otherstuff
#0       5           x
#1       2           x
#2       7           x
```

Comment: This is the best I think. I believe you can just have `value.max()` as opposed to `transform` though :)

Comment: @Mitch Hmm. That does seem to work. But the performance is affected on large data set (probably due to the join process incurred by the unequal length).

Answer (score 2):

You could sort by `value` to ensure you will take the maximum, then group by the index and take the first member for each group.

```
(df.sort_values(by='value', ascending=False)
   .groupby(level=0)
   .head(1)
   .sort_index())
```

Which yields

```
   value otherstuff
0      5          x
1      2          x
2      7          x
```

Comment: This is fantastic and fast, though it drops duplicates.

Comment: @JakeMorris ahh I didn't see you wanted to keep duplicates. Maybe I'll think some more about this.

Comment: I didn't realize I had any, actually. When the dataframe I got trying your method was 2 rows smaller than the dataframe I got trying Scott Boston's, I did a delta and realized there are duplicates. My real 'value' column is so precise I didn't even think I'd have the same value again.

Comment: In that case Psidom's answer is probably best.

Answer (score 0):

Without `groupby` you can suing `sort_values` and `drop_duplicates`

```
df2['INDEX'] = df2.index
df2.sort_values(['INDEX', 'value'],ascending=[True,False]).
    drop_duplicates(['INDEX'],keep='first')

Out[47]: 
   value otherstuff  INDEX
0      5          x      0
1      2          x      1
2      7          x      2
```